# Does StockTwits messages/create API also post on my Social Media accounts

Tags: twitter, stocktwits

Does the [messages/create](http://stocktwits.com/developers/docs/api#messages-create-docs) API call post on Social Media accounts linked using the "Social Connections" page under "Settings" in addition to StockTwits?

Is the [messages/create](http://stocktwits.com/developers/docs/api#messages-create-docs) API call considered equivalent to entering a post in the text field that contains "Share an idea" on my home screen on StockTwits?

Answer (score 1):

Even though the StockTwits web site allows users to push a post to other social media, the messages/create API call does not.